# how to update warn deprecated

Tags: node.js, express, npm, deprecated

I'm trying to learn node and npm, using express for a little project.
When i install it, i got

```
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.10: core-js@<3.0 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
```

I understood that if everything works, it's not necessary to update everything, but i'm trying to learn and go the extra, unnecessary, mile.

How can i update only core-js?

```
npm install core-js@^3
```

will update it adding it to the dependencies in package.json.

Is this the right way to do it?
Or it's better to update the parent package that use it? If so, how can i understand which is the package that need an update and how to update it?
Or is there a way to update only the modules listed in package-lock.json.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just doing - npm i core-js

Comment: isn't it the same thing as npm install, just the shorter way. It add the package as a dendencies in package.json...

Comment: Most likely, your project does not depend on core-js directly, but on another package that depends on it. Adding core-js won't fix that, you'll have to find out which dependency depends on the outdated core-js, then update that. You can use the npm ls command for that

Comment: `npm ls core-js`, see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls.html

Comment: @PatrickHund .... that's what i was looking for, thanks for your answers. Now that i know what package has the depracated module how can i update it? In this situation is pug which is already at the last version (2.0.4). I now know that its dependencies pug-code-gen use an outdated version of constantinople; but, only for the sake of my knowledge, is there a way to update it locally? I know that it works but what if i'd like to update it anyway?

Comment: To my knowledge, you don't have a lot of options other than submitting a ticket to the pub library authors, or a pull request to their repo to update the dependency yourself

Comment: Thanks, that's what i wanted to be sure of.

Answer (score 2):

You provided one way to update a package. However, there are a few more.

To update a global package, you could run:

```sh
npm update -g <package_name>
```

To update a package that's in your `package.json` (i.e., local to your project), run:

```sh
npm update <package_name>
```

You could also see what outdated package are there as follows:

```sh
npm outdated
```

You could again add `-g` option to check outdated *global* packages.

Sources: https://docs.npmjs.com/updating-packages-downloaded-from-the-registry

Also: `man npm` may help (in Linux).

Comment: It's not a global package so i'm not using the -g flag. Also i already updated every dependencies in package.json, but it seems that even the last updates use older version of core-js. How can i manually update only the package in package-lock.json?

Answer (score 1):

To update to a new major version all the packages, install the npm-check-updates package globally:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

this will upgrade all the version hints in the package.json file, to dependencies and devDependencies, so npm can install the new major version.

You are now ready to run the update:

```
npm update
```

or `npm install`